# Regex ignore special ASCII characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading a bunch of files from a `PERL` script : css, html, js, png, jpg and i want to print only the text. The script is using this regex :

```
if($substring4 =~ /[A-Za-z0-9 \t\n\r]/)
{
    print("GOOD ...\n");
    print($buffer);
}
else
{
    print("INVALID ...\n");
    print($buffer);
    print("\n\n");
}
```

Witch is not working well :

**Marked as good :**

```
--G=154 W=164 F=168 L=512--
GOOD ...
unload=null)}}},simulate:function(a,b,c,d){var e=f.extend(new f.Event,c,{type:a,isSimulated:!0,originalEvent:{}});d?f.event.trigger(e,null,b):f.event.dispatch.call(b,e),e.isDefaultPrevented()&&c.preventDefault()}},f.event.handle=f.event.dispatch,f.removeEvent=c.removeEventListener?function(a,b,c){a.removeEventListener&&a.removeEventListener(b,c,!1)}:function(a,b,c){a.detachEvent&&a.detachEvent("on"+b,c)},f.Event=function(a,b){if(!(this instanceof f.Event))return new f.Event(a,b);a&&a.type?(this.originalEven

--G=155 W=165 F=169 L=512--
GOOD ... ===> GOOD, it must accept those characters
t=a,this.type=a.type,this.isDefaultPrevented=a.defaultPrevented||a.returnValue===!1||a.getPreventDefault&&a.getPreventDefault()?K:J):this.type=a,b&&f.extend(this,b),this.timeStamp=a&&a.timeStamp||f.now(),this[f.expando]=!0},f.Event.prototype={preventDefault:function(){this.isDefaultPrevented=K;var a=this.originalEvent;!a||(a.preventDefault?a.preventDefault():a.returnValue=!1)},stopPropagation:function(){this.isPropagationStopped=K;var a=this.originalEvent;!a||(a.stopPropagation&&a.stopPropagation(),a.cancel

--G=156 W=166 F=170 L=512--
GOOD ... ===> GOOD, it must accept those characters
Bubble=!0)},stopImmediatePropagation:function(){this.isImmediatePropagationStopped=K,this.stopPropagation()},isDefaultPrevented:J,isPropagationStopped:J,isImmediatePropagationStopped:J},f.each({mouseenter:"mouseover",mouseleave:"mouseout"},function(a,b){f.event.special[a]={delegateType:b,bindType:b,handle:function(a){var c=this,d=a.relatedTarget,e=a.handleObj,g=e.selector,h;if(!d||d!==c&&!f.contains(c,d))a.type=e.origType,h=e.handler.apply(this,arguments),a.type=b;return h}}}),f.support.submitBubbles||(f.ev
```

**Marked as invalid when it should be arked as GOOD, there are normal characters there, that you find on the keyboard:**

```
INVALID ... ===> WRONG, it must accept those characters
/^(?:button|input|object|select|textarea)$/i,t=/^a(?:rea)?$/i,u=/^(?:autofocus|autoplay|async|checked|controls|defer|disabled|hidden|loop|multiple|open|readonly|required|scoped|selected)$/i,v=f.support.getSetAttribute,w,x,y;f.fn.extend({attr:function(a,b){return f.access(this,a,b,!0,f.attr)},removeAttr:function(a){return this.each(function(){f.removeAttr(this,a)})},prop:function(a,b){return f.access(this,a,b,!0,f.prop)},removeProp:function(a){a=f.propFix[a]||a;return this.each(function(){try{this[a]=b,delet

INVALID ... ===> WRONG, it must accept those characters
""),e=0,g=Object.prototype.toString,h=!1,i=!0,j=/\\/g,k=/\r\n/g,l=/\W/;[0,0].sort(function(){i=!1;return 0});var m=function(b,d,e,f){e=e||[],d=d||c;var h=d;if(d.nodeType!==1&&d.nodeType!==9)return[];if(!b||typeof b!="string")return e;var i,j,k,l,n,q,r,t,u=!0,v=m.isXML(d),w=[],x=b;do{a.exec(""),i=a.exec(x);if(i){x=i[3],w.push(i[1]);if(i[2]){l=i[3];break}}}while(i);if(w.length>1&&p.exec(b))if(w.length===2&&o.relative[w[0]])j=y(w[0]+w[1],d,f);else{j=o.relative[w[0]]?[d]:m(w.shift(),d);while(w.length)b=w.shift(
```

**Marked as GOOD but must be marked as bad, wired characters ... from a image of ssl certificate**

```
--G=722 W=723 F=749 L=512--
GOOD ... ===> WRONG, it must skip those characters, mark them as bad character
£©4Óô]>E‘Ÿ0AN=Går™ÉÉI²µ0ô ªªÒÒÒB"‘ ‹Õ-ûÚ×¾V'ü®¼òJxàz{{ë\+1Óñ>Ÿßþíß¦³³“Ûn»T*…ëºüþïÿ>K—.eË–-}˜‹ùåá”âåüÃA½yBpðŠw‘mïdã¯ŸÃ0+³Ë~äájàÝ÷êéõÇ:~<EÁ±†¢é¡P„ñÔ(¥R‘þeç`š&““D"ú–,edd„J¹L1B+[”
¹ª ,9xð @µ:«iúŽ ãxa›.™Lšó×\À¦ËÞmšDÃšâ2–JQÌÑ[[)UòÅRM„+57¸ZYÔÐTÎ]ÞË²žv†F’âÀ¡A†F’ÕFì®‹¦iâò ‚°håÿgïÍãä¨ëüÿgÝÕÇô\=÷ä"„%‚«‚(ä0(‚úÔwYýŠ+»®« +*ÊOEQÔu¿_—å'‡À*» ‚,"§ˆrGH$dÎÌÝ÷Qç÷êª©é™   dfrÔ3JuWW×çÓ=]UŸ×ç}½ðÂ¼ðÂ<ýôÓ¼üòËŒ“ÉdÈf³X–53Å¾ ÐØØHcc#étš•+Wò¦7½‰ÉÉI¾ùÍoû……_ÄÎáÀSO=•;ï¼“uëÖ‘Ïç)—Ëœ{î¹<üðÃ³

--G=723 W=724 F=750 L=512--
INVALID ... ===> GOOD, it must skip those characters, mark them as bad character, i don't know why here is working
,¨û+Ñ]4""bIð­põq€a (Š>„Çšš9ò¡{Iò»ÜŽ»ù%ŠŸ»ûŸ.Fÿ‹Ã‚ãî³ÐuA&ˆ"í]à:H²— EQ5Ç%›ÍÏçH&’È²ˆ$
ä²’©®£T¥\©`T«<÷ÜslÛ¶\.G6›
Jxø³Ú…|ž|.Çú³Ï£©¹Ë²hIÆ(—Ë¼üòTY&‹‘ÏeÉçstvõ Ë
ã£4¤Ñc1,Û¦û-üá‰gx~ãKàz¿Q’ˆòuFDD,óÅÕmÜ¸‘{î¹‡{î¹‡§žzŠÁÁÁ]:v>Ÿg`ÀixðÁ¹öÚkg¼¾víZn»í¶ÂoŸ½_í&ê¿Ÿ7¿ùÍÜxãœsÎ9T*&&&øÈG>Â<0Ëâº?‰¿ˆˆˆ%cGq€õÀ‚$ñä©ë9ø÷¾¦8@²*_ûö‡Ï'~ú»÷Ù8ÀZ5¾ AeÛ6‘%™öö.ª¦®é¤Óí$“)ôXÃ¨ÒÝÝÍÈÈ(åR‘TcŽš`t ×u1“‘‘LÓ¤Z­Ö?Çq0M“¾mÛXsèZÞúöu¸ŽW€=•TÎÒØÜ‚}¸£    IDAT"Iˆ’„išH¢ˆã:ò9&'ÇM÷ŠÑ[Ž—f*“Å¶t-Êj±øÔß,ËâW¿ú
```

I want a regex that accept all characters that you may find in a `html`, `xml`, `json`, `css` file but exclude the ones like `sÎ9T*&&&øÈG>Â<0Ëâº?‰¿ˆˆˆ%cGq€õÀ‚$ñä` wich can be found when reading a picture.

My curent regex is :

`/[A-Za-z0-9 \t\n\r]/`

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the samples that you say are being marked as GOOD or INVALID. Are you saying that you are testing those code strings? You are testing `$substring4` but your test prints `$buffer`, so we cannot see the string being tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to select lines consisting exclusively of visible ascii characters and/or `\t`, `\r`, `\n`:

```
if ($substring4 =~ m/\A [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]* \z/xms) {
    print STDOUT "GOOD ...\n";
}
```

Remarks

- the whole line has to be matched: `*`
- `\n` and `\r` are not portable in perl, use `\x0A` and `\x0D` instead
- the modifiers `ms` and the anchors `\A`, `\z` are recommended for binary patterns
- the modifier `x` allows formatted regexps (whitespace ignored)

Comment: *“the modifiers `ms` and the anchors `\A`, `\z` are recommended for binary patterns”* That isn't true. Modifiers `/m` and `/s` affect only the behaviour of metacharacters `^`, `$` and `.`, and you have none of those in your pattern. `\A` is only different from `^` in the presence of `/m`, and the same applies to `\z` except it can be useful to avoid matching before a newline at the end of the string

Comment: The expanation above is completely correct. In Perl Best Practices, Damian Conway recommends to always use the modifiers `xms` and the anchors `\A` `\z`. Anyone may agree or not, it is just a recommendation.

Comment: PBP is very out of date now, but in this regard nothing has changed. But it has nothing to do with *“binary patterns* whatever they may be

Comment: I think this is the answer, i testetd that and works fine, but i don't quite understand how it is working ... they are like allow between ASCII hex x09 and ASCII hex x7E ?

Comment: @Damian, the simpler [\x09-\x7F] is also possible, but less accurate. [\x00-\x1F\x7F] are control characters, of which only \x09 (tab) \x0A (line feed) and \x0D (carriage return) occur in usual plain text. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking for, but you could try checking for any non-ASCII characters, or ampersand or angle brackets.

Like this

```
if ( $buffer =~ /[\P{ascii}&<>]/ ) {
    print "INVALID\n";
}
else {
    print "GOOD\n";
}
print $buffer, "\n\n";
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but, now it gives me invalid all the way http://pastebin.com/QPHDZFje

Comment: @Damian: Okay, but you still haven't explained what data you're testing, and what `$substring4` is. I need an example of data that is incorrectly coming up as invalid. And what is your pastebin? Is that the contents of `$buffer`? Because there are no invalid characters in that

Comment: thank you so much for your answers, but i switched to `node.js` ... much stable and faster, with `perl` i cannot view 2 sites at the time, with `node.js` i can ...